# after modify script, sEcho result not same

Tags: php, jquery

how to make the response result at `sEcho` become not zero?

```
{"sEcho": 0,
```

i've been use this code but result still zero..

```
 $sOutput .= '"sEcho": '.intval($_POST['sEcho']).', ';
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here.   `intval(postVar('sEcho'))` returns zero, so you get zero.  Perhaps if you looked in to why it's returning zero, you'd find your answer?  Also, it looks like you're building JSON. [`json_encode`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is your friend.

Comment: `$sOutput .= '"sEcho": 1, ';`? Also, this is a pretty appalling way to generate JSON when you have libraries to do it for you.

Comment: This looks like the example code from http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: @all: see at my question i've been change it

Comment: The answer remains the same.  `intval(postVar('sEcho'))` is returning zero.  If you find out why `intval(postVar('sEcho'))` is returning zero, you'll find your answer.

Comment: @Charles: i'm a beginner..i'm confuse that why sEcho result is different how to make it same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, time to elevate this to an answer.

```
 $sOutput .= '"sEcho": '.intval(postVar('sEcho')).', ';
```

This line takes the output of the function `postVar`, when given the paramater `'sEcho'`, then takes that result and runs it through the built-in function `intval`.

That integer is then appended using the `.` concatenation operator to the string `'"sEcho":'`, which is then appended to the variable `$sOutput`

`intval` turns whatever it was passed into an integer.  This is like casting.  Pretty much any string is turned into zero.  `intval('YOUR FACE IS ON FIRE')` will return 0, `intval('')` will return 0, etc.

I don't know where `postVar` is, but I'm going to wager based on the [provided example code link](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) that it's some ill-conceived wrapper around `$_POST`.  So, another way to write it *might* be:

```
$sEcho = (int)$_POST['sEcho'];
$sOutput .= '"sEcho": ' . $sEcho . ', ';
```

The bottom line is that the thing being passed to `intval` is turned into zero.  It's very likely that the input named "sEcho" is not a string that can be turned into anything but zero.

That's where your zero is coming from.

To fix it, you need to pass something to `intval` that won't get turned into a zero.

---

As a side-note, if you're actually using the linked example code, you should probably be aware that the code in question is complete, utter garbage.  It's filled with bad practices, like persistent connections, the use of the outdated `mysql` extension, manual assembly of JSON strings, and the most horror of horrors, a poorly thought out Hungarian Notation style.  Seriously, sEcho being a thing that was cast to an integer?  Shouldn't it be iEcho then?  Sigh.